# linux ens4 network interface stop and start

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, interface

When i use ifconfig ens4 down and ifconfig ens4 up in the google vm the connection does not return and remains down

```
sudo -s
apt install screen
screen -s test sh start.sh
ctrl + a + d
```

```
echo "1"
ifconfig ens4 up
sleep 5
echo "2"
ifconfig ens4 down
sleep 5
echo "3"
sleep 5
ifconfig ens4 up
echo "4"
```

stop after ifconfig ens4 down and dont execute ifconfig ens4 up

so i restart on the google cloud console panel to return to normal

I need to turn it off and on to put the machine in bridge mode, but it stops working when ens4 is turned off even using screen -s test sh start.sh;

i also try

```
ip link set dev ens4 up
```

i update for: [linux bridge.sh connection lost](https://serverfault.com/questions/1021951/linux-bridge-sh-connection-lost)

Answer (score 3):

When the interface is brought down, any manual route associate to an IP address on this interface is deleted. When the interface is brought up, this(ese) manual route(s), most certainly including the *default* route is(are) still lost.

For modernity, I'll replace any occurence of `ifconfig ens4 down` by (using full syntax) `ip link set dev ens4 down` and `ifconfig ens4 up` by `ip link set dev ens4 up`

Let's suppose *ens4* should be assigned 192.0.2.2/24 with a default route using 192.0.2.1 as gateway.

---

### Current problem

Add address:

```
ip address add 192.0.2.2/24 dev ens4
```

Bring interface administratively up:

```
ip link set dev ens4 up
```

If there was no `noprefixroute` option in the address, then this route is automatically (=> `proto kernel`) added when the interface is administratively brought up:

```
192.0.2.0/24 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link
```

(If the command was `ip address add dev 192.0.2.2/24 dev ens4 noprefixroute` then the config would also have had to add the route manually with eg `ip route add 192.0.2.0/24 dev ens4`.)

Add default route:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 dev ens4
```

Bringing the interface up again has simply no effect. Now once the interface is brought down, any route requiring its address disappears (in a chain effect): 192.0.2.0/24 and thus the *default* route since it depends on a route to 192.0.2.1.

Once the interface goes up again, only the automatic (*proto kernel*) *scope link* route comes back, not the manually added default route: connectivity stays lost. Just add again this default route:

```
ip link set dev ens4 up
ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 dev ens4
```

---

### About bridging

Suppose there's a bridge called `bridge0`.

```
ip link add name bridge0 type bridge
ip link set dev bridge0 up
```

When an interface becomes a bridge port, with something like:

```
ip link set dev ens4 master bridge0
```

Routing stops for this interface: packets received on it are forwarded to the bridge, and not to the IPv4 routing layer anymore (details in this [blog](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-linux-bridge-isolation#bridge-processing), check bullet 5). But at the same time there's a route staying defined on the interface if not removed, which can confuse the network stack for outgoing packets, Strict Reverse Path Forwarding etc.

So all addresses have to be removed (=> automatically removes routes too) from it preferably before, eg:

```
ip address flush dev ens4
```

and added to the bridge instead, as well as the default route:

```
ip address add 192.0.2.2/24 dev bridge0
ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 dev bridge0
```

All these steps disrupt networking for a few seconds, so should be performed automatically, with console access, or even all at once within a *screen* layer.

Comment: i type your code using "screen -s test bash start2.sh" and "ctrl a d " and no work
```
echo "hello"
sleep 20
echo "world"
ip link set dev ens4 down
ip link set dev ens4 up
ip address add 10.128.0.58/20 dev ens4
ip link set dev ens4 up
ip route add default via 10.128.0.58 dev ens4
ip link set dev ens4 up
ip route add default via 10.128.0.58 dev ens4
sleep 20
ip link set dev ens4 up
```

Comment: i also try your code for bridge, and also no work

Comment: i try in debian 10, debian 9, ubuntu 18, ubuntu 16 and centos 6

Comment: ip route add default via 10.128.0.58 is wrong: it's the server's address instead of the router's address. Use the router's address for gateway

Comment: i am using google cloud always free nic0(ens4) 10.128.0.58

Comment: Actually some basic informations from your question are missing. You should update your question. While the server is reachable, run this, and add the commands and their result in the question please: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route`

Comment: if you are afraid just use avg secure vpn to protect yourself

Comment: avg secure vpn is best que nordvpn, no is necessary register and is free and is 5MB

Comment: because of these types of comments showing fear, I think that community users are bots;

Comment: look the print: https://prnt.sc/t1nkw8

Comment: I'm done with this until the question is updated

Comment: i dont undersantd, update what?

Comment: look the sample script from openvpn tutorial page https://prnt.sc/t1nltd

Comment: sometimes I think that you learn more from my attempts than I learn from your instructions as none work;

in windows it is so simple to bridge between 2 network adapter; but i can't put windows on google always free since it asks for the serial port;

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1021951/linux-bridge-sh-connection-lost